# React.js handling 3rd party library mounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, c3.js

I'm seeing an awkward bug using a third party library inside of a react component. I was able to reproduce a contrived demo for this post.

Let me start by explaining that I am using c3js - which is a charting library and rendering it in `componentDidMount()` and removing it in `componentWillUnmount()` with the correct calls to `this.chart.destroy()`.

**The bug occurs when filtering the components themselves, essentially what happens is the components are filtered correctly but the actual chart that sits inside the component stays the same as the first chart, which is very strange behaviour. Basically it's the wrong chart inside the wrong component!**

You can see what I mean by clicking on the `Remove all charts except chart 3` button, I have labeled the charts with a `chartid` and the filtering will correctly remove the other charts.

I am fairly certain it isn't my code because the filtering works correctly and updates the view. You can verify because I have labeled the charts and it is visible in the view. There is no console errors and I have verified my code works.

So my question is - can we work around this limitation using c3js, or is this really a problem with my code and the way I am rendering the charts.

Related demo: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/38614/

Related code:

```
var data = [
  {
    chartid: 1,
    columns: [
                ['x', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                ['data1', 130, 300, 330, 400, 300, 400, 500],
                ['data2', 390, 230, 200, 150, 100, 130, 210],
                ['data3', 290, 430, 300, 160, 210, 170, 190],
                ['data4', 190, 330, 200, 260, 190, 250, 320]
    ]
  },
  {
    chartid: 2,
    columns: [
                ['x', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                ['data1', 130, 300, 330, 400, 300, 400, 500],
                ['data2', 390, 230, 200, 150, 100, 130, 210],
                ['data3', 290, 430, 300, 160, 210, 170, 190]
    ]
  },
  {
    chartid: 3,
    columns: [
                ['x', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                ['data1', 130, 300, 330, 400, 300, 400, 500],
                ['data2', 390, 230, 200, 150, 100, 130, 210]
    ]
  }
];

var Button = React.createClass({
  handleDelete: function (id) {
    this.props.handleDelete(id);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
         <button onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(null, 3)}>
            Remove all charts except chart 3
         </button>
    )
  }
});

var Chart = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    this.chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '.chart-' + this.props.data.chartid,
        data: {
            columns: this.props.data.columns
        }
    });
  },
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.chart.destroy();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{"chart-" + this.props.data.chartid}</h4>
        <div className={"chart-" + this.props.data.chartid}>
        </div>
      </div>
      )
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  renderCharts: function(data) {
    return data.map(function(metrics, i) {
      return (
        <Chart key={i} data={metrics} />
      )
    });
  },
  handleDelete: function(id) {
    this.props.handleDelete(id);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
       <div>
         <Button handleDelete={this.handleDelete} />
         {this.renderCharts(this.props.data)}
       </div>
    ) 
  }
})

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      initialData: this.props.data
    }
  },
  handleDelete: function(id) {
     var _filterFunc = function(data) {
       if (data.chartid == id) return true;
       return false;
     };

     var _filterCharts = Array.prototype.filter.call(this.state.initialData, _filterFunc);

     this.setState({
        initialData: _filterCharts
     })
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child handleDelete={this.handleDelete} data={this.state.initialData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you are setting the key on your chart. It's causing the renderer to get confused about which chart you're trying to keep.

Try this:
`<Chart key={data[i].chartid} data={metrics} />`
instead of `<Chart key={i} data={metrics} />`

Take a look at how [React handles keys](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children). Remember that you're *uniquely identifying* a child with a key for the lifecycle of the component. So since chart 1 is uniquely identified by key "1", you can't render chart 3 with key "1." My solution above ensures that the chart is uniquely identified by its chart id instead of by its rendering order.

Comment: Yes you are right!. It makes sense since the keys I was assigning were actually just based on the `map` loop and not actually related to the charts so I assume - chart 3 was receiving `key={1}` when it was being filtered. Am I correct in stating that?

Comment: That's exactly right. The behavior is a bit counterintuitive, but remember it's optimizations like these that allow React to have the high performance it does.